# What does 'Make app public' do in Facebook Android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

Under 'App review' there's an option to make your app public. Right now it says 'No' and 'Your app is in development and unavailable to the public'. What happens if I switch it to yes though. Will my friends be able to see the app i'm working on (I don't want that). So how do I keep my app development private, but at the same time be able to use it's features. Because as I'm aware, I have to turn 'Make app public' to 'on' in order to utilize Facebook login for my app.

Comment: You can test everything will the app is in development mode, it doesn’t need to be live for that. (Content published through the app will become visible to all users only after you made it public though.)

Comment: Are you referring to the actual app going live on the Play Store or just making the app public in the Facebook SDK?

Comment: The latter - making the app public via the switch in app dashboard.

Comment: This video I used to implement the Facebook SDK says you have to turn it on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrAXmZkOpJI&t=14m29s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your friends wont be able to see the app you are working on. Making your APP public is for your clients to use it's features and not just the developer.

Comment: So if I make the app public, there's no way anyone apart from me can find/use the app?

Comment: Yes. No one except you can find this.

Comment: I would not rely on that; it is still possible for your app to show up in search results for example.

Comment: Search results from where?

Comment: I have made apps public on Facebook. None of my friends can find this even after they search using the exact app name. @cbroe can you please specify using which search can this app be accessed

Comment: I said it is possible, but not necessarily the case for every app. Just don’t rely on that it will _never_ be found by anyone, once it is set public.

Answer (score 0):

It means you are in development mode now. If you make it public, then only you can access your login from other devices. And this does not say to post your wall or mention your friends.

> while an app is in sandbox mode/development mode, so “not live”, only
>   the users added as admins, developers, testers to the app can use it
>   and see content that was created through it. Only when you put it in
>   live mode, every user will be able to use it and see content made via
>   it.